# Angular 2 Material `md-select` with custom template

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I'm searching the way to use custom template for Angular 2 material's `md-select`, but it seems like I can use only default text selection. I'm trying to implement a dropdown like this:

[image]

I need to have such template in `md-option`s and in `md-select` after selection one of my `md-option`s. Is there a way to get the following result via Angular 2 material's `md-select`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just came across the same problem. It seems that content works as expected but it's just the mat-option that doesn't want to resize automatically. The solution that worked for me is just to transclude divs with your desired content into  and **specify mat-option  height**. Possiblt you'd also like to modify line-height Like this:

```
 <mat-form-field>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Select" aria-label="subject" matInput formControlName="subjectInput" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let item of items | async" style="height: 60px; line-height: normal;">
       <!-- your content here -->
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is same as @Kamil's answer but cleaned up a bit. I'm also using [flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) for flexbox directives.

```
  <mat-option class="customer-search-result"
              *ngFor="let option of searchResults" [value]="option">

       <div fxLayout="column">

           <span class="name">{{ option.fullName }}</span>
           <span class="email">{{ option.email }}</span>

       </div>

   </mat-option>
```

And the sass

```
mat-option.customer-search-result
{
    line-height: normal;

    .name {
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .email {
        color: gray;
    }
}
```

Be sure to do `mat-option` and not `.mat-option` so you don't need to worry about shadow DOM.

Note that there is a `<span class='mat-option-text'>` inserted which you may need to restyle too.